# Using Socket.io with EJS causes error "Can't set headers after they're sent"

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ibm-cloud, ejs

I am trying to make an app with Node.js, Express and Socket.io on IBM Bluemix I'm using EJS as the view engine. This is the relevant part of my code -

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//copied from socket.io tutorial 
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../templates'));
...
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    logger.info('index');
    return res.render('index');
});
...
const port = process.env.PORT || localConfig.port;
http.listen(port);
```

Now if I navigate to localhost:3000, I get the error

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
at ServerResponse.header (/home/aniket/Documents/HumbleHelper/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.contentType (/home/aniket/Documents/HumbleHelper/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:595:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/aniket/Documents/HumbleHelper/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:145:14)
at done (/home/aniket/Documents/HumbleHelper/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1004:10)
at tryHandleCache (/home/aniket/Documents/HumbleHelper/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:228:10)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/aniket/Documents/HumbleHelper/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
at View.render (/home/aniket/Documents/HumbleHelper/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (/home/aniket/Documents/HumbleHelper/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
```

From the log, I can see that 'index' has been called twice, followed by the error. However, if I remove this line -

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

It works fine. I have read other questions which mention that calling res.*** functions more than once might cause this issue. My guess is that constructing socket.io over the server causes something.

Versions:

socket.io: 2.0.4

express: 4.6.2

ejs 2.5.7

node: 6.9.0

**EDIT**

After commenting/uncommenting all the modules, I've found the cause here, at the top of my app

```
require('appmetrics-dash').attach();
require('appmetrics-prometheus').attach();
```

Comment: `return res.render('index');` return not needed

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN removing the return causes the same error

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're constructing the socket.io listener to handle a res. So when Socket.io receives another broadcast, it uses the previous res which has already sent.

To fix this, remove the listener after you're done with it so you can construct a new listener with the new res. For Instance:

```
socket.on('example', function(data){
     socket.removeAllListeners('example');
     res.send(data);
});
```

EDIT: Whoops! Somehow I read the question wrong lol. Try this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
```

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.My guess is that letting socket.io and express listen on the same port is causing the error